# SQL: Order By dictated by a different table

Tags: sql

Hopefully very simple SQL question - I'm just blacking out :)
I have a table of vendors (id, name, description, url). It used to be the web service returned them all sorted by id. After a while, I was asked to return sorted by name. Now they want me to allow them to change the order manually - to showcase new vendors.

Suppose I create another table, VendorOrder with (vendorid, placement), what can I put in the Order By section of the original query, to return the vendors sorted by placement?

As always, thanks in advance.
Guy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
  vendor.id,
  vendor.name,
  vendor.description,
  vendor.url
from 
  vendors,
  vendorOrder
where
  vendors.id = vendorOrder.vendorId
order by 
  vendorOrder.placement;
```

Make sure that you find *exactly one* vendorId in `vendorOrder` for each `id` in `vendor`, otherwise use a `left join` between the tables.

Comment: Thanks @Rene, this answers my question .You do have a typo though that you may want to edit: in the Where clause, should be vendors.id = vendorOrder.vendorID - you're missing a . and have an extra =

Comment: @Traveling Tech Guy: Thanks for pointing out my typo, it's corrected now.